# What is the inventory item after the pogo stick?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm missing the item after the pogo stick in the inventory although I'm already at the castle, what is it and how can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

You get in it the caves, when you keep wandering you see an arrow on one of the doors, if you follow it there will be another arrow and another till you find a chest.  It is called A heart plug and increases your health points by 20%.

Comment: You did not say what the item is. You should edit that in to make this a complete answer.